# Excel's automating a TFS update using VBA won't work in Workbook_Open function

Tags: excel, vba, tfs

I am trying to automate a workbook so that when it is opened it will automatically update the TFS data and send an email. I can update the TFS data successfully using a macro (found code on this [blog](https://blogs.infosupport.com/connect-tfs-to-excel/#respond)) however when I run the code from the Workbook_Open event it errors out with "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' Method 'execute' of object '_CommandBarButton' failed". I looked at [How do I resolve a VBA 'Method Execute of a [TFS Excel Add-in CommandBarButton] failed' Run-time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045517/how-do-i-resolve-a-vba-method-execute-of-a-tfs-excel-add-in-commandbarbutton/56046417#56046417), but that solution doesn't work for me. This actually makes sense to me because the workbook hasn't actually connected to TFS yet - that happens AFTER the Workbook_Open completes.

My question is, is there an event after the TFS Database connection is made that I can call my code from or is there a way to force the TFS connection first? I have tried doing Application.Wait and Sleep, but that just delays the TFS Database connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried doing Application.Wait and Sleep, but that just delays the TFS Database connection.

That's because these methods essentially pause the current (one and only) thread; they won't let any other (non-VBA) code run in the meantime.

> the workbook hasn't actually connected to TFS yet - that happens AFTER the Workbook_Open completes.

Sounds like you need to *defer* execution then. Move the `CommandButton.Execute` code to another procedure, and then use [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) to schedule the execution of that procedure, say, 5 seconds later - assuming you pulled the offending code to some `UpdateTFS` procedure:

```
Application.OnTime DateTime.DateAdd("s", 5, DateTime.Now), "UpdateTFS"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That is exactly what I needed to do. This works like a charm now!