# Execute action failed on CommandBarButton to update workitems

Tags: excel, vba, tfs

I am using the below code to click on Refresh button on Team menu to update the work items in ADO. I have a similar code to click on New List button on Team menu to configure a new query. I keep getting an error message "Method execute of object '_CommandBarButton' failed. I had to close the excel and re-open to get the macro working.

```
Private Function FindTeamControl(tagName As String) As CommandBarControl
    Dim commandBar As commandBar
    Dim teamCommandBar As commandBar
    Dim control As CommandBarControl

    For Each commandBar In Application.CommandBars
        If commandBar.Name = "Team" Then
            Set teamCommandBar = commandBar
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not teamCommandBar Is Nothing Then
        For Each control In teamCommandBar.Controls
            If InStr(1, control.Tag, tagName) Then
                Set FindTeamControl = control
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Function
Sub RefreshTeamQuery(shtTFSExcel_Name As String) '(rangeName As String)

    Dim activeSheet As Worksheet
    Dim teamQueryRange As Range
    Dim refreshControl As CommandBarControl

    Set refreshControl = FindTeamControl("IDC_REFRESH")

    If refreshControl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find Team Foundation commands in Ribbon. Please make sure that the Team Foundation Excel plugin is installed.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If 

    'Disable screen updating temporarily so that the user doesn’t see us selecting a range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Capture the currently active sheet, we will need it later
    Set activeSheet = ActiveWorkbook.activeSheet
    Set teamQueryRange = Worksheets(shtTFSExcel_Name).ListObjects(1).Range

    teamQueryRange.Worksheet.Select
    teamQueryRange.Select
    refreshControl.Execute

    activeSheet.Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, it is highly recommended not to use reserved words as variable names (`Dim commandBar As commandBar`). I would recommend that you change the variable name to something like: `oCommandBar`. Second, have you tried stepping through your code to see which line throws the error?

Comment: Hi - I tried this and ran into the same run time error again. So I added a wait step and an explicit command to check if the team menu's refresh button is enabled. Also display a message to let the user know if the refresh button is not enabled. This stopped the run time error. Whenever the refresh command is not executed, now the excel will display a message to introduce an explicit wait and avoids the macro from being stopped.

Comment: Hi @GaneshDee28. Glad to know that you have found the method to solve this issue. Could you share it in answer and accept it? This will be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following VBA sample:

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("A2").Select
RefreshTeamQueryOnWorksheet ("Sheet1")

End Sub
Private Sub RefreshTeamQueryOnWorksheet(worksheetName As String)

    Dim activeSheet As Worksheet
    Dim teamQueryRange As Range
    Dim refreshControl As CommandBarControl

    Set refreshControl = FindTeamControl("IDC_REFRESH")

    If refreshControl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find Team Foundation commands in Ribbon. Please make sure that the Team Foundation     Excel plugin is installed.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Disable screen updating temporarily so that the user doesn’t see us selecting a range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Capture the currently active sheet, we will need it later
    Set activeSheet = ActiveWorkbook.activeSheet
    Set teamQueryRange = Worksheets(worksheetName).ListObjects(1).Range

    teamQueryRange.Worksheet.Select
    teamQueryRange.Select
    refreshControl.Execute

    activeSheet.Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function FindTeamControl(tagName As String) As CommandBarControl

    Dim commandBar As commandBar
    Dim teamCommandBar As commandBar
    Dim control As CommandBarControl

    For Each commandBar In Application.CommandBars
        If commandBar.Name = "Team" Then
            Set teamCommandBar = commandBar
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not teamCommandBar Is Nothing Then
        For Each control In teamCommandBar.Controls
            If InStr(1, control.Tag, tagName) Then
                Set FindTeamControl = control
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Function

Sub UpdateAndExportBurndownCharts()
    RefreshTeamQueryOnWorksheet ("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

Based on my test, I  run into the same issue.

> "Run-time error 'xxx' Method 'execute' of object '_CommandBarButton' failed"

Then I add the code and it could work.

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("A2").Select
RefreshTeamQueryOnWorksheet ("Sheet1")

End Sub
```

For more detailed information, you could refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045517/how-do-i-resolve-a-vba-method-execute-of-a-tfs-excel-add-in-commandbarbutton).